# Amcharts: Is there a way to control zoom level of the chart by custom buttons?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using `serialChart` provided by amCharts.

It is possible to have `chartScrollBar` to control the zoom level of the chart but is it possible to have custom zoom-in and zoom-out buttons that control the same functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to control the zoom through external buttons, but you're limited to the serial chart's zoom API methods. For a date-based chart, you can use [`zoomToIndexes`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#zoomToIndexes), and [`zoomToDates`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#zoomToDates), whereas a non-date based categoryAxis supports `zoomToIndexes` and [`zoomToCategoryValues`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#zoomToCategoryValues). To zoom completely out, you can use the [`zoomOut`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#zoomOut) method.

Here's a [demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/5ad2f052d8e8e1c6e381179de9667a80) that has external form elements and buttons that call each of the zoom methods for a date-based chart.

Comment: Reposting my response from the AmCharts support forum in case anyone else is also looking for this.

Comment: Thank you very much, your demo helped a lot. The answer is perfect as aspected.